# 'str' object has no attribute 'META' in function when retrieving request.META

Tags: python, django

These are my functions for country detection using IP.

```
from unipath import Path
import pygeoip

# Country Detection
def get_ip_address(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip

def geoip_country(request):
    path = Path(__file__).ancestor(3)+"/scripts/notes/custom_packages/geoip/GeoIP.dat"
    geoDetect = pygeoip.GeoIP(path)
    return geoDetect.country_code_by_addr(get_ip_address(request))

def get_user_location(request):


    ip = get_ip_address(request)
    ip_country = geoip_country(ip)
    user_location = (ip_country)

    return user_location
```

When I am calling this function in view by passing request object like this:

`get_user_location(request)`

I am getting `'str' object has no attribute 'META'` error  where as if I print `request.META` in `get_ip_address` function, its printing in console without any error. What's wrong here ?

Comment: Evidently you're passing a string, not a request object.

Comment: You should really study the *full traceback* of the exception (and *always* post it when asking a question). I was able to mentally trace the problem here, but your traceback would have told you directly that the string came via `geoip_country()`.

Comment: Side note: `user_location = (ip_country)` is just the same thing as `user_location = ip_country`. You may as well use `return ip_country`. Did you mean to return a *tuple*? In that case you are missing a comma; `return ip_country,`

Comment: yeah you are correct @MartijnPieters . I don't need tuple here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in the `ip` argument to `geoip_country()`:

```
ip = get_ip_address(request)
ip_country = geoip_country(ip)
```

but your `geoip_country()` function expects a `request`:

```
def geoip_country(request):
```

which it then passes on to `get_ip_address()` *again*:

```
return geoDetect.country_code_by_addr(get_ip_address(request))
```

Change the `geoip_country()` function to expect an `ip` instead:

```
def geoip_country(ip):
    path = Path(__file__).ancestor(3)+"/scripts/notes/custom_packages/geoip/GeoIP.dat"
    geoDetect = pygeoip.GeoIP(path)
    return geoDetect.country_code_by_addr(ip)
```